# Convert various types of date time to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#

I am facing different problem in visual c#. I am importing some data in to C# from excel, the Excel files coming from different locations.

Some excel files date is in string format and in some files date is in date format. In that data one column is there date. There they typed date in different formats.

For example some typed in format of `dd/mm/yyyy` (01/10/2011), some typed `dd.mmm.yyyy` (01.oct.2011), some typed `yyyy.mm.dd` (2011.10.01) and more.

So I want to convert all that date formats in to `dd/mm/yyyy` in visual c#. If date is string format only or any other single format i can. But here input records are in various formats.

Comment: What you tried so far? Just to confirm, datetime coming from excel is of type string,right?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` with 3 format strings?

Comment: Note that if you have mixed dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy then it's unlikely you can achieve this unless you have some other data indicating which format the date is in (since dates like 10/12/2020 are ambiguous - is it December 10th or October 12th?). It doesn't sound like you have this kind of combination, so I imagine you'll be OK with `ParseExact`.

Comment: @prasad Telkikar date time coming from different excel files and some in string format and some in date format .

Answer (score 1):

You should add dates formats to yours app config files

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="FormatsDate" value="MM/dd/yyyy;yyyy-MM-dd;dd.MM.yyyy;dd/MM/yyyy" />
  <add key="CultureInfoName" value="en-GB" />
</appSettings>
```

And use it in you code

```
string[] dateFormats = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FormatsDate"].ToString().Split(';');
string cultureInfoName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CultureInfoName"].ToString();
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact("Value From excel column", dateFormats, new CultureInfo(cultureInfoName), DateTimeStyles.None);
```